# Java beginner: Switch statement does not give expected output

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement

```
    char suit = 'S';
    int n = 2;


    for (int k= 0; k<4; k++){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        switch (k) {
        case 0: suit = 'S';
        case 1: suit = 'H';
        case 2: suit = 'D';
        case 3: suit = 'C';
        }
```

This is a code excerpt from an assignment.

Suit is set to 'C' after the switch statement, and it never changes throughout the double loop, according to the debugger. What have I misunderstood about the switch-statement?

Comment: add break; to each case and default to the end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
switch (k) {
        case 0: 
          suit = 'S'; 
          break;
        case 1: 
          suit = 'H';
          break;
        case 2: 
          suit = 'D';
          break;
        case 3: 
          suit = 'C';
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
```

without the `break;` you enter each case block till the first `break` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a break statement at the end of each block like so:

```
switch (k) {
        case 0: 
          suit = 'S'; 
          break;
        case 1: 
          suit = 'H';
          break;
        case 2: 
          suit = 'D';
          break;
        case 3: 
          suit = 'C';
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
```

If you do not end a block with a break statement your switch will continue onto the next block and execute that code too (if the case is valid).

usages where this behaviour might be desired can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)